# How to solve Bad Request Error on HttpClient Post Request Java

Tags: java, post, apache-httpclient-4.x

### Post Request HttpClient with JWT token (Bad Request Error found /chunked:false)

```
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(RestUrl.SAVE_INVENTORY);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(inventoryDto);
        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(json);
        httpPost.setEntity(entity);
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        httpPost.addHeader("Authorization", "JWT " +LoginDaoIMPL.token);
        CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
        client.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

The API was expecting "Bearer" instead of "JWT" so the problem was with this code

Answer (score 0):

It could be this line of code that is giving you trouble:

```
 httpPost.addHeader("Authorization", "JWT " +LoginDaoIMPL.token);
```

Notice you have a space after the word `JWT`. Remove the space.